# PHP: Bootstrap Buttons Not Evaluating/Registering

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

The following code is **HTML** for a form through **Bootstrap 3**. All the `CSS` and `JS` is stock. This snippet is part of a bigger form that is of method post and the action loops the page (that is to say the action is the same `URL` as the page itself).

```
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">

                                <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-5 control-label"><abbr title="Please select how you are paying today">How Are You Paying Today? (Optional)</abbr></label>


                                    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="button" name="cash" id="cash" checked><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span> Cash</button>
                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="button" name="card" id="card" checked><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></span> Card Of Some Sort</button>
                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="button" name="IOU" id="IOU" checked><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> IOU (Favor)</button>
                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="button" name="Other" id="Other" checked><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> Other</button>
                                    </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>
...
```

This is a basic test method to see if cash is selected.

```
                        <?php 

                            if(isset($_POST['cash']))
                            {


                                echo "cash selected";

                            }

                        ?>
```

Nothing echoed. Eventually I want to have it where whichever button is selected gets passed to a `PHP` script to be stored in a database. But when the form is submitted, it looks like the button is selected, but it does not get submitted. Still pretty new to **Bootstrap**, so I'm learning all the `CSS` tricks and what not.

Any ideas why this information isn't passed to the `PHP` script?

EDIT: Updated some code at the advice of Fred. Here is the present HTML.

```
                                    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="button" name="cash[]" id="cash" checked><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span> Cash</button>
                                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="button" name="card[]" id="card" checked><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></span> Card Of Some Sort</button>
                                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="button" name="IOU[]" id="IOU" checked><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> IOU (Favor)</button>
                                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="button" name="Other[]" id="Other" checked><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> Other</button>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: `<button type="button"` will not work for POST method. Use `<button type="submit" ...  name="cash"...`

Comment: use `checkbox` or `select`

Comment: I just noticed the "checked" part. @Waki is right. Since you have 2x elements of the same name. You would also need to change that to `name="cash[]"` because you'll only get one value back and needs to be treated as an array. Or use a `<select>` as Waki said and use a submit button to process the whole thing. However, what I initially said, still does stand true about button types.

Comment: I take it the array principle needs to be applied to all names? @Fred-ii-

Comment: Yes, if you wish to keep your present code/method.

Comment: Sidenote: My bad; I thought you had 2x elements with the same name.

Comment: Care to go a little more into the <select> snippet you were talking about earlier @Fred-ii-

Comment: The thing is, if you're running your entire code from within the same file, you will need to encapsulate your PHP inside a conditional statement from a named submit button. I.e.: `if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['cash'])){ echo "cash selected"; }` as for the added brackets you added `[]` in your edit, those weren't meant for all of them, only for elements bearing the same name, which doesn't apply. I'd just use a dropdown. I'll try and put something together in an answer to better illustrate.

Comment: @AndrewL I've posted something for you to look at below.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices. A dropdown select or radio buttons, which would give them only a single option.

Dropdown select:

```
<select size="1" name="payment">
    <option value="cash">cash</option>
    <option value="card">card</option>
    <option value="IOU">IOU</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

or radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" value="cash" name="payment">Cash
<input type="radio" value="Card" name="payment">Card
<input type="radio" value="IOU" name="payment">IOU
<input type="radio" value="Other" name="payment">Other

<input type="submit" value="Submit payment" name="submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset">
```

Then do:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['payment'])){

    $payment = $_POST['payment'];

    echo $payment;
}
```

Comment: I like! Will try this out. Thanks @Fred -ii-